# Complete Review of Small Application

Tags: discussion, code-length

I have written a fairly small application (10 small classes). I have tried to follow best practices in terms of software design but I have a feeling it can be improved.

It is acceptable for me to post the entire application's code in codereview-se to be reviewed, or is that too broad.

I don't really have any specific questions but rather "please review my code and offer improvement suggestions". I probably could extrapolate individual questions but I think it would be best to see everything in context of the entire application. I would of course explain what the application does and a high level overview of its design also.

So I just want to check here first before posting such a question

Answer (score 19):

There is a 30k character limit to post questions on all Stack Exchange sites; Code Review's is over 65K.

If it fits into one question, then you may absolutely ask it. Otherwise, perhaps you will find a way to split it up into two questions, or ask about a particular part in your application.

For applications of this site however, it is **very important** that you include *a lot* of explanation and context about what your project is about.

I have myself asked questions on Code Review about quite big code projects, see for example:

- [Analyzing Minesweeper Probabilities](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/54737/analyzing-minesweeper-probabilities)
- [SudokuSharp Solver with advanced features](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/37448/sudokusharp-solver-with-advanced-features)

Explaining a lot about your code in plain English really helps reviewers to better understand and review your code.

Comment: "Applications of this site"? Did you mean "application of this __size__"?