# Is it appropriate to ask for review on an entire GitHub repo?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, code-length

I have a Python application that I created a while back and I'm hoping to have someone with more Python experience than me look over the entire project and let me know if both the structure of the application and the code itself can be improved in any way.

Would it be appropriate for me to post a link to the repo and ask for an overall review?  It's not a particularly large project, but pasting all of the code into the question wouldn't make sense.

Comment: Related questions: https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1475/31562 https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1338/31562 https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6735/31562 https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6025/31562 https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5430/31562 https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5129/31562 https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2324/31562 Does any of those questions answer your question? If so, which? :)

Comment: Relevant: [How to NOT to write a zombie](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2320/23788) and [Simon's checklist for a good CR question](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6429/23788).

Comment: Also: [How to get the best value out of Code Review?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436/23788)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, it wouldn't be ok. Your question would get closed quite quickly, with a dedicated close reason, stating:

[image: Questions must include the code to be reviewed]

> Questions must [**include the code to be reviewed**](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3653/23788). Links to code hosted on third-party sites are permissible, but the most relevant excerpts must be embedded in the question itself.

Only the code that's embedded in the post is reviewable. Link to GitHub is only provided as a convenience to reviewers that might want additional/complete context. Read the link for the whole reasoning, and/or any of the linked questions @Simon provided.

Answer (score 6):

To add to Mat'sMug's answer, it is best to focus on individual pieces of code, chances are that reviews of that code will be applicable to the rest of your project.

I would suggest that you find some code related to a specific aspect of the program, maybe some that you find have the most room for improvement, and post it and apply the answers to your project, then post other questions with some of the improved code.